# Create three columns layout, all dynamic

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout

I want to create a dynamic website in asp.net using MVC model from Visual Studio 2013.

All the columns will have dynamic content, each one changing it's content on different selections based on user actions or by the controllers.

How can I create those three dynamic columns?

I already have my layout in HTML and CSS but I need to separate those three columns and have the possibility to change their content from my controllers.

Later edit:
In my case I have two menus in the website, one to the left and the other one to the right. Actually they are three with the other one from the top. When I select something from the top, the menu from the left must be showed depending on the top selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate each column by using `ViewBag` or `ViewData`. So in the Layout, use this data to pupulate this columns, for example:

**1) Calling this action will change the content for something that you specify:**

```
public ActionResult MyView()
{
  // you can put anything in this ViewBag, 
  // a string, a list of something and then use it in the view
  // Its dinamyc

  ViewBag.Column1 = "My content column 1";
  ViewBag.Column2 = "My content column 2";
  ViewBag.Column3 = new string[] {"Product1", "Product1", "Product1"};
}
```

**2) Consume this data in your layout to generate the dynamic content:**

```
<div id='column1'>
  @ViewBag.Column1
</div>
<div id='column2'>
  @ViewBag.Column2
</div>
<div id='column3'>
  <ul>
  @foreach(var s in ViewBag.Column3)
  {
    <li>
      @s
    </li>
  }
  <ul>
```

You should take a look here for more information:

- [What is ViewData, ViewBag and TempData?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem)

You should use **Sections** as well, take a look here:

- [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is a solution because I have to repopulate those three columns in each Controller. The second approach with Sections seems a better way. I will try to make a few test for my case and I will come back with details.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to make three different Controller Actions. For Example:

```
public ActionResult Part1()
{
return View();
}

public ActionResult Part2()
{
return View();
}

public ActionResult Part3()
{
return View();
}
```

And then call them in your Common page.
Example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.Action("Part1")
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.Action("Part2")
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.Action("Part3")
    </div>
</div>
```

You can have the selection criteria controls inside the view of the controllers. i.e. if you need a drop down list for the First Block. Place it in the Part1 View. Also to make it async you can have Ajax forms in all three views.

Comment: Does this mean that every controller must have all these three ActionResults?

Comment: No. Only one controller will have it and then you can use it anywhere. To access it from other controller you can use @Html.Action("Part1","ControllerNameWherePart1IsDefined")

Comment: Yes, but I still have to call it! I think I have a solution for this but I don't know how good it is. I was thinking to have a basic controller in which I define those three parts and then, at the end of the controller code I will call the left and right View()s. The center column is the main View().